# Silex Function Tests with PHPUnitTest

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

Good morning,

I am attempting to setup some test using `Silex\WebTestCase` to ensure that my application is working properly.  In order to do that I need to load up some referential data into the backend storage.  I am using ElasticSearch with the https://github.com/doctrine/search library.

I thought that the best way to do this was with Fixtures, namely symfony/data-fixtures.  However I am unable to work out how to use them.  This is because the fixtures need to implement the `FixturesInterface` that states the `load()` method should recieve a compatible Doctrine ObjectManager, however as I am using the Search library I do not think I have such an object.

As this is for test data then I could write something that is home grown but I would like to use things that are appropriate and written for this scenario.

Does anyone have an examples of using fixtures in a Silex application that I could at least look at to point me in the correct direction?

Thanks, Russell

Comment: Did you end up finding out how to do this?

Comment: @grim No I did not find a way to do this using the FixturesInterface

Comment: Too bad, thank you anyway. If I find the answer I'll post it here.